# sql sort with default value always on top

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i want to sort a column INITIALS that stores initials of people. The default value for the column is "N/A". After the sort all the rows with the default value should be display first and then the rest should be sorted. so if i have something like ..

AB
ZY
EG
UI
FE
EE
N/A
UY
N/A
YX

after the sort it should be

N/A
N/A
AB
.
.
ZY

the simple sort will display the all the "N/A"s in the middle. how would i achieve this? thanks

Comment: @Clodoaldo i'm using sql server 2008 thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select ...
from ...
order by case mycol when 'N/A' then 0 else 1 end, mycol
```